# Is it correct to apply "Housewife" term for an unmarried woman who does house-chores?

Tags: grammatical-gender

I would like to know what is the appropriate label to describe a young woman/girl who is unmarried, stays in her parents' home, does the house chores, and has no income. She is not also looking for a paid job. I am wondering if it would be correct to apply the "housewife" term to describe her occupational status? Many thanks for your help

Comment: **homemaker**:a person, especially a woman, who manages a home.(https://www.google.co.in/search?dcr=0&source=hp&ei=ZIfLWpWCGpa6vwSWk76oBw&q=homemaker+meaning&oq=homemaker&gs_l=psy-ab.1.1.0i131k1j0l9.1002.4656.0.7310.10.9.0.0.0.0.192.1206.0j8.8.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..2.8.1204.0..46j0i46k1j0i131i46k1j46i131k1.0.Ur-3Ct0tmxw)

Comment: it's an interesting question.  it's not unheard of to jokingly call **a single man** who does household chores, "a housewife".  (Also, "haus frau".)  Further, I've always thought that "housewife" actually suggests you are *married to the house*; you're "tied" to it, it's your "lot in life"; you could use it in that sense.  "A housewife at 17 !"  Anyway, the simple answer to your question is "no".  And like choster, I don't believe there's a word for this thing (which is **extremely uncommon** in English-speaking countries).

Comment: Housekeeper, not housewife.

Answer (score 2):

No, she is not a housewife.  ***Housekeeper*** is a correct term, according to [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/housekeeper).

> 1 : one employed to manage the domestic duties involved in maintaining
>   a house
>
> 2 : **a member of a household who manages the domestic duties of the
>   household ·She was her father's housekeeper** …  —Lucy Maud Montgomery  (Emphasis added)

In the case the OP cites, **the young woman is her parents' housekeeper.**

Comment: The second meaning has very little currency in the U.S. outside of HR departments and literary fiction. If someone says a woman is her parents' housekeeper, the implication is that a family member is being treated as a low-ranking servant, and the family may be insulted or scandalized.

Answer (score 1):

A *[housewife](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/housewife)* is (MW)

> a married woman in charge of a household

One can be a wife in the household who is not a *housewife*, such as an elderly mother-in-law, and one can be responsible for domestic affairs without being a *housewife*, such as a housekeeper. But to be accurately labeled a *housewife*, one must be both.

The term *housewife* is somewhat out of favor, at least among the Western intelligentsia. Maybe twenty years ago it would have been a fairly neutral term, but now it is considered too freighted. On the one hand, some consider *housewife* too passive; people in that role may prefer the more active and gender-neutral *homemaker*, or *stay-at-home mom/dad/parent* if they are caregivers for children. From another side, television shows like *Desperate Housewives* and *The Real Housewives of [X]* have contributed to the idea of a "housewife" as a wealthy socialite with dysfunctional social relationships, further diminishing the term's appeal.

I'm not familiar with any particular term for the type of person you describe, as most labels for domestic workers— like *[domestic worker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domestic_worker)* itself— are typically reserved for people who are not members of the family. Someone might complain of having to serve as the *chauffeur* or *cook* or *maid* and so on for the other members, but this is done in jest, especially in a household that has no domestic help.

She could plausibly describe herself as a *homemaker*, or a *[nanny](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanny)* if the primary function is looking after children, or say she is a *domestic* if answering a government survey.

Comment: Right. The only phrase I can think of that I would use to describe this is a "stay-at-home daughter".

Comment: If it is a light-hearted situation (ie, *not* a case of, the mother is deceased, there was no life insurance, and the older daughter has to do everything), you could use "haus-frau", I guess.  (Just as you can when humorously referring to a male who is doing the household chores regularly.  it's the humorous, "Mr Mom" self-deprecating version of "housewife".

Comment: It occurs to me most English speakers would get the construction "Miss Mom".  "Since Mrs Smith died suddenly, young Jane has been Ms. Mom to the whole house."  Anyway.

Comment: Dear choster and Fattie, Many thanks for your fruitful answers. One more question about "unemployed" title. Can I apply this term to describe someone who doesn't have a job at present and is not looking for it?

Comment: @SMM *Unemployed* may mean different things in different places, but in the U.S., it applies only to those who are both looking for paid work and who are not working at least part-time. It does not apply, for example, to students, retirees, the idle rich, or those unable to work due to illness/injury/disability, either in common usage or in government statistics.

Answer (score 1):

While this is extremely common experience, more so for non white americans, and people around the globe outside of America, there isn't really a term for this. If you wish you may go into detail when describing to someone, otherwise probably just saying that the girl lives at home and people can deduce the rest.